# Método de fechar uma Activity

Tags: android

Boa noite, em minha aplicação fiz um DialogFragment coloquei uma função de fechar activity atual e voltar para anterior, a chamada coloquei no `onBackPressed()` e o código que faz essa função esta no onclick do "OK"... só que está me apresentando um erro no LogCat

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

DialogFragment:

```
    package com.gif.popupsair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;


public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private Activity getActivity;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builderr = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builderr.setMessage("Isso e um dialogFragment").setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                getActivity.finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        builderr.setTitle("Hello Mundo");
        AlertDialog dialog = builderr.create();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Segunda Activity:

```
package com.gif.popupsair;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    public void AbrirDialog(View view){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aperte o botao para voltar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        MyDialog di = new MyDialog();

        di.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "my_dialog_tag");
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.gif.popupsair, PID: 1370
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.finish()' on a null object reference
                      at com.gif.popupsair.MyDialog$2.onClick(MyDialog.java:24)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Nome da primeira Activity: MainActivity

Obrigado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fechar uma activity e "voltar" para a anterior, basta chamar o método ***finish();***

Feito isso na segunda activity, ele fechará a mesma e voltará para anterior, no caso a sua activity "pai" que chamou ela.

**Exemplo Activity Um**

```
public class ActivityUm extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_um);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityUm.this, ActivityDois.class);
        startActivity(intent); //Abre a segunda activity
    }
}
```

**Activity Dois**

```
public class ActivityDois extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button botao;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dois);

        botao = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botao);
        botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                finish(); // Finaliza essa activity e volta para anterior
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Lembrando que ao pressionar o botão "voltar" do celular, já é chamado o método **onDestroy()** que tem por função "destruir" a activity, portanto ao entrar na segunda tela e pressionar o botão voltar do celular, ele fará a função do método **finish()** que associamos ao clique de um botão na tela.

Portanto neste caso, você pode remover o método **onBackPressed()**, que ele realizará a função nativa de voltar e destruir essa activity.

Comment: Então amigo.... criei um popup que aparce quando clicar no botão do voltar do celular e nisso me da a opção de  **ok** e **cancel**... na class no `setPostive` que seria o "OK" coloquei a função `onDestroy();` e não está indo, por que?

Comment: @Nathan, na classe *MyDialog* e no *onClick()* do botao OK chame o método `getActivity.finish();`.

Comment: @Luídne o meu funcionou dessa forma - `getActivity().finish();`... Obrigado pela ajuda.